# How to change text opacity using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, css, element, opacity, innerhtml

Hi i was just wondering if there was a way to change the opacity of text using innerHTML almost as a container...

```
var x = document.getElementById("myId");
x.innerHTML.style.opacity = .5;
```

???  maybe something like that?  I had an idea to have a different class and just add that class to specific HTML but im trying to grab the html of an element, change the text opacity to a lighter shade, delete it from the element but keep it in a variable, add in new html, and then add the original html but i want the new html to be darker than the original so i cant change the opacity of the element otherwise it will effect all the text in the element.  If anyone has any suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.  I am trying to use only HTML, CSS, and Javascript so im trying to avoid any added libraries if i can help it.  thank you.

Comment: If you want only transparency on the letters, not the container, you will have to set the `color` as a rgba-value. `.myTransparentText { color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) }` will for example make your text black with 50% opacity on the letters. There is no other option. http://www.css3.info/introduction-opacity-rgba/

Comment: since you want to change the innerHtml for an element , why not change this parent element opacity instead?

Comment: ok let me try that and see if i can do anything about it.  the effect im trying to go for is present in the text based game "a dark room" by doublespeak games if you want to see what i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could changes the opacity of all childrens

```
var childrens = document.getElementById("myId").children;

for(var i = 0, length = childrens.length; i < length; i++) {
    childrens[i].style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```

Comment: i tried this and after running some tracers through the code it says that everything is correct but the text is not changing so i will have to tweek with this a little bit later.  thank you i didnt think about using the children.

Answer (score 0):

No far ... like that :

```
var x = document.getElementById("myId");
x.style.opacity = .5;
```

Comment: i cant do this because im trying to change only parts of the text not the entire element.

Comment: Years later, I realized this was the simple answer.  Sorry for my ignorance.  I simply didn't have a good understanding of javascript dom manipulation or what I was doing for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

you can use x.style.opacity = 0.5

**update :** since you need to change only one part of the text ,, you should do something like this

```
x= document.getElementById("id");
x.innerHtml = "not important text <div id='important'>Important</div>";
document.getElementById("important").style.opacity = 0.5;
```

Why do you want to do something like this?? can you explain more ,, So we can help you ?

Comment: i cant because im trying to only change parts of the text not the entire element.

Comment: Years later, I realized this was the simple answer. Sorry for my ignorance. I simply didn't have a good understanding of javascript dom manipulation or what I was doing for that matter.